# Why does codelite not open the lldb or gdb debuggers?

Tags: codelite

System:  M1 mac with 16G of memory, OS Ventura.

My large application with codelite builds fine with g++ and comes up and runs. There are features that don't work correctly, so I need a debugger. When I try to start either lldb or gdg either something flashes on the monitor and stops or simply just does nothing. Codelite has worked well for me for 13 years. I hope someone has a similar problem. My only choice now is to use lldb from the command line, and this is difficult for me.

I changed debuggers frequently tried to acquire an older version of codelite, asked for help on ther codelite forums and got no response.

Answer (score 0):

CodeLite no longer supports `lldb` directly (on all platforms).
It has moved to use the new `DAP` (Debug Adapter Protocol) method of debugging code.

- On macOS, you should install `lldb-vscode` via `brew`:

```
brew install llvm
```

- In CodeLite make sure that the `DebugAdapterClient` plugin is loaded: `Plugins -> Manage...`
- Force a new scan: `Settings -> Debug Adapter Client` and CodeLite should detect the new debugger
- In your project, change the debugger to `lldb-vscode`

You can read more about DAP integration here:
https://docs.codelite.org/plugins/dap/

Comment: I followed the instructions for installing llvm but the "Debug Adapter Client" does not appear in the list of available plugins.

Comment: which CodeLite version are you using?

Comment: I am using codelite version 16.0.0 built from brew. It is indicated by brew be to the most recent version. Even without being able to run the plugin DebugAdapterClient, if I set the debugger to '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/15.0.6/bin/lldb-vscode', a single window appears with tabs "Locals"  "Watches", ...

Comment: The more recent version is 17.0.0 in brew. Can you try it? 
https://docs.codelite.org/downloads/download/#macos

Comment: I cannot install codelite 17.0.0 with brew, only 16.0.0. Is there a direct download you have available.

Comment: I found codelite 17.0.0, and it does not run on an M1 mac. It comes up and crashes in a few seconds.

Comment: You should use `brew` (it installs other dependencies as well). What is not working for you from this document: https://docs.codelite.org/downloads/download/#macos ?

Comment: This all I get when I set a breakpoint and start debugging.

Comment: Hit return too quickly.Working directory is set to: /Volumes/HermesSSD/DiscreteMathCalculatorProject-current/build-Debug
Executing:  /tmp/codelite-exec.sh
/Volumes/HermesSSD/DiscreteMathCalculatorProject-current/build-Debug/DiscreteMathCalculatorProject.app
Hit any key to continue...

Comment: Codelite17.0.0 crashes frequently on my M1 mac. I have had to go back to 16.0.0. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but the problem may be the Apple Silicon (M1) mac processor. I will move my project to Xcode. Thanks again.